# Version Roll Back

Tags: linux, version, rollback

I am doing a concept in linux in which i want to do version rollback for an app installed in linux. Is it possible??

For eg I have an application named X with version 1.1
I get an update. It changes it to version 1.2
I note what all the packages in the app going to be modified.
Then i save them and apply the changes.
Now after sometime due to some problems I want to switch back to version 1.1
If i undo the changes and make the entire solution will the rollback be done?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and common way in Unix is to install them in separate directories,
eg "/usr/bin/MyApp.1.2.3"  and "/usr/bin/MyApp.1.2.4" then create a link to the one to use "/usr/bin/Myapp".
Changing versions is then just a matter of moving the link.

Comment: Yeah i understand these things but my project deals with optimization. I had to optimize the disk space. If u consider the difference between two versions it won't be much. So just noting the changes done and saving them will help minimize the disk space. – DG 0 secs ago

Comment: Then just install using SVN-export. If this is an app being distributed to customers than most of the packaging tools rpm/deb/etc can undo an installation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to invent anything. Just keep the packages you install around. If you want to go back, uninstall the current version and install the previous package again.

Comment: Yeah i understand these things but my project deals with optimization. I had to optimize the disk space. If u consider the difference between two versions it won't be much. So just noting the changes done and saving them will help minimize the disk space.

Comment: openSUSE creates diffs between RPMs. Check this project: http://freshmeat.net/projects/deltarpm/